# Ionic Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, undefined, ionic3

I've read others entries but still I don't know how to solve my problem. The issue is the next one:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ng:///AppModule/MyApp.ngfactory.js:105:62)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14730:21)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13866:14)
>       at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14211:21)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14143:13)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13867:5)
>       at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14211:21)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14169:17)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13862:5)
>       at callViewAction (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14211:21)

And the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()

export class AppState {
_state = {}

constructor() {
}

get state() {
   return this._state = this._clone(this._state);
}

set state(value) {
   throw new Error('do not mutate the `.state` directly');
}
get(prop?: any) {
   const state = this.state;
   return state.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? state[prop] : state;
}
set(prop: string, value: any) {
   return this._state[prop] = value;
}
_clone(object) {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
}
}
```

Using Ionic3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `this.state` instead of `this._state`

Answer (score 0):

It seems for me that the error is coming from here:

```
const state = this.state;
```

You have `this._state` in your service and not `this.state`

Comment: No, the problem is still there.

Comment: @BryanArreolaMurguía, could you please show how you are accessing the property `_state` of the service inside your component ?

Comment: @BryanArreolaMurguía, I mean how are you calling the function inside the code you posted ? Did you make the change I suggested ie, changing this line `const state = this.state;` with this one `const state = this._state;`?